# Efficent way to generate a summery table in SQL. Please see explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am very new to sql.I need some help in generating summery information

**MemberTable**

```
MonthID  | UserID  | TeamID
-----------------------------
  1      |  1       | 1
  1      |  2       | 1
  1      |  3       | 1
  1      |  4       | 1
  1      |  5       | 2
  1      |  6       | 2
  1      |  7       | 2
```

AND

**ReportTable**

```
ID* |  MonthID  | UserID  | IsSend
-----------------------------------
 1  |    1      |    2     | False
 2  |    1      |    3     | True
 3  |    1      |    5     | True
```

I want to generate a summery like the following

```
TeamID     |  Total Count  |  Send Count | Not Send Count
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1         |      4        |      1      |     3
 2         |      3        |      1      |     2
```

> **Total Count**    : No of users in a team
>
> **Send Count**     : Total User in a team with IsSend = True
>
> **Not Send Count** :  Total Count - Send Count

What would be the efficent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select MT.TeamID,
       count(distinct MT.UserID) as "Total Count",
       count(distinct case when RT.IsSend = 1 then MT.UserID end) as "Send Count",
       count(distinct MT.UserID) - count(distinct case when RT.IsSend = 1 then MT.UserID end) as "Not Send Count"
from MemberTable as MT
  left outer join ReportTable as RT
    on MT.MonthID = RT.MonthID and
       MT.UserID = RT.UserID
group by MT.TeamID
```

Result:

```
TeamID      Total Count Send Count  Not Send Count
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1           4           1           3
2           3           1           2
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66347

Comment: I like the use of the data explorer - not something I knew existed!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select mt.teamId, count(*) totalCount,
    count(case when rt.isSend = 'True' then 1 end) sendCount,
    count(case when rt.isSend != 'True' then 1 end) notSendCount
from memberTable mt
join reportTable rt on mt.userId = rt.userId
group by mt.teamId
```

Note that your expected result does not reflect your data. The result based on your data should be:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| TEAMID | TOTALCOUNT | SENDCOUNT | NOTSENDCOUNT |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+
|      1 |          2 |         1 |            1 |
|      2 |          1 |         1 |            0 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: No actually the users whose report isn't created in "report table" should be considered as "not send"

Answer (score 0):

Without havign the tables to try this on, I can't check that this will work, but this shoul get you most of the way:

```
SELECT TeamID, count(userID) as "Total count", Sum(IsSend) as "Send Count" FROM MemberTable JOIN ReportTable ON UserID GROUP BY TeamID;
```